# Different header template for cms pages

Tags: wordpress, templates, header

I would like to use two different header templates for a website. One for the home page and in other cms pages the layout will be different. Can anyone please help me out with it?

Comment: Just make a template for home, and select that on the page. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Comment: Tried that. Didn't help. Need to create an if else statement in header I guess. Looking for that kind of a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There are two ways:

1- 

  <?php if (is_front_page()): ?> 
        home header codes 
  <?php endif; ?> 
        other pages header codes

2- You should have two header files like:  header.php  & header-home.php : 


 <?php 
    if (is_front_page()){
      get_header('home');
    }
    else {
      get_header();
    }
    ?>
```